Security of $E(c,k) = AES(c,(k \oplus c)\cdot (2^{n} - 1 - c)) $ used multiple times with low bit keys $k$. Avoids MitmA?
More precisely the Encryption function will be $E(c_i,k_i,i)$ with a 128-bit cipher/number $c_i$, a 16-bit encryption key $k_i$ and a 8-bit index $i$ as input using a

Xor key obfuscation $k'$ with the first 16-bit of the cipher $c_i$
$$ k_i' = k_i \oplus c_{i,{[1:16]}}$$

value shift to guarantee different numbers for all $k_i'$ and 48-bit $c_{i,{[17:64]}}$
$$c_i' = 2^{64} - 1 - c_{i,{[17:64]}} $$

combine them to a 80-bit value $K_i$
$$K_i  = k_i' \cdot c_i' $$

and finally we use it concatenated with the 8-bit index $i$ as a 88-bit symmetric key $[i,K_i]$  in a normal AES in ECB - mode
$$
\begin{split}
E(c_i,k_i,i) & = AES(c_i,[i,K_i]) = c_{i+1} \\
 & = AES(c,[i,(k_i \oplus c_{i,{[1:16]}})\cdot (2^{64} - 1 - c_{i,{[17:64]}} )])\\
& = c_{i+1}
\end{split}
$$



The Decryption $D(c_{i},K_i^{-1},i)$ with 80-bit input value $K_i^{-1}$ and 8-bit index $i$ would be:
$$ \begin{split}
D(c_{i},K_i^{-1},i) &= AES^{-1}(c_i,[i-1, K_i^{-1}]) \\
& = c_{i-1}
\end{split}$$
Furthermore we need to check if $K_i^{-1}$ was a valid key
$$| K_i^{-1} \cap \{K_{i-1}\}| 
 \not= \{\}$$
It need to be a multiple of $c_{i-1}'$
$$ \begin{split}
K_i^{-1} &\overset{!}{=} c_{i-1}' \cdot k_{i-1}' \\
K_i^{-1} &\overset{!}{=} (2^{64}-1-c_{i-1,[17:64]}) \cdot k_{i-1}' \\
\end{split}$$
With  $k_{i-1}'<2^{16}$. Else it will get rejected. 
For a random $K_i^{-1} > 0 $ every $k'_{i-1}>0$ should have the same probability and with this also $k_{i-1}$ (or not?).
$$k_{i-1}=k_{i-1}'  \oplus c_{i-1,{[1:16]}}$$
If we pick $K_i^{-1}>0$ more carefully we can't get better than a chance of $1:2^{48}$ picking a valid key (or not?).
For $K_i^{-1}=0$ we have a special case leading to $k'_{i-1} = 0$ giving us one solution for the forward key
$$ \begin{split}
k_{i-1} & =0  \oplus c_{i-1,{[1:16]}} \\
k_{i-1} & = c_{i-1,{[1:16]}}
\end{split}
$$

Goal:
This special case $K_i^{-1}=0$  is intended.
Different to normal encryption we do not want to encrypt any messages but instead the relation in between numbers $c_i$.
Given two (random) $c_j,c_j^*$ we want to prevent finding a common ancestor $ĉ_i$ together with keys $k_{i},k_{i+1},..,k_{j-1}$ and $k_{i}^*,k_{i+1}^*,..,k_{j-1}^*$ leading to $c_j$ and $c_j^*$
So for example:
$$
\begin{split}
E(ĉ_i,k_i,i) & = ĉ_{i+1} \\
E(ĉ_{i+1},k_{i+1},i+1) & = ĉ_{i+2} \\
....\\
E(ĉ_{j-1},k_{j-1},j-1) & = ĉ_j = c_j \\
\end{split}
$$
Indices $i,j$ are bound to their 8-bit size and can not surpass their borders $0 \le i,j < 2^8$ 

Attack:
For simplicity we assume $j-i > 16$ to make it (almost) certain such an ancestor $ĉ_i$ exists. 
Meet in the middle attack should be the most promising.
Given $c_j,c_j^*$ we can make use of $K_m^{-1} = 0$ and $k_m = c_{m,[1:16]}$ producing possible ancestors and successor for all indices $m$ (except borders).
Next we can e.g. start at $c_0$ and compute $S$ successor and for $c_j^*$ find $A$ ancestors and let them meet at index $m$ with $i < m < j$
With $c$ values being 128-bit this should take in mean
$$E(|S \cap A| > 0 ) \approx \frac{\sqrt{2^{128} \pi}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\approx 2^{64}$$
generated values in forward and backward direction. 
However finding valid ancestors only works in $1:2^{48}$ cases. So the total number of  calculated AES will be $\approx 2^{64+48} = 2^{112}$
We can decrease the total costs by generating more in forward direction and less in backward direction. 
Optimum should be
$$S \approx 2^{88}$$
$$A \approx 2^{40}$$
Keeping the number of AES calculations about equal on both sides.
Total costs $\approx 2^{88}$ AES calculations needed.
Not super secure but good enough for target app. 
Current bitcoin network computation capability would need about 12 days for it ($2^{68}$ AES/s, assuming 2 hashes = 1 AES) and would have a power cost of at least \$3 millions (\$0.001/kWh)
(There will be some further step only allowing $\approx 1:2^8$. We ignore this here)

Question:
Did I miss something? Is there any faster way to find a common ancestor?
$K^{-1}$ does already partly revealing some part of a possible ancestor. Does this help us finding one?
Will the total amount of AES calculations change significantly if we search an ancestor not only for $c_j,c_j^*$ but instead any two out of $N < 2^{33}$ different values with index $j$?
If I'm not mistaken it should not get lower than $2^{87.3}$ (related math question)

Further nodes:
For higher security we could increase the bit length of $c_{i,17:64}$.
 48-bit was chosen to keep as short as possible while still being secure enough.
Alternative for $c_i',K_i$ we could not subtract $c_{i,{17:48}}$ from $2^{64}$ but instead replace it with the $(6543+c_{i,{[17:48]}})$'th prime number or split it in 3 primes  $p(6543+c_{i,{[17:32]}})$ $\cdot$ $p(6543+2^{16} +c_{i,{[33:48]}})$ $\cdot$ $p(6543+2^{17} +c_{i,{[49:64]}})$ for not too big look-up-tables.
Will this change something about the security? (any shorter bit idea ?)

One must ask: why? What is your motivation to invent a wild new encryption method? What are you trying to accomplish? Why does a standard method not meet your needs?

@Mikero It will be used as a multi-dimensional embedding of locations which are represented by $c$. Given two (random) locations the path in between should be unknown. A common problem with multi-dimensional cryptography is it does either need a lot of bits or can easily be reduced to 1 dimensional much simpler problems. Both should not happen. Looking for smallest location number possible while locally propagation should still be easy to do. $i$ describing the granularity or Z-axis. $k$ the combined X & Y-axis. Special case $K^{-1}=0$ needed to have at least 1 possible easy propagation in Z

I'm sorry to admit that your explanation was not helpful for me. Standard/modern cryptography can encrypt arbitrary bytes very effectively. It doesn't matter whether the bytes represent images, family recipes, nuclear launch codes, or "multi-dimensional embedding of locations". Again I would ask, what is preventing you from treating your data as plain old bytes and encrypting them in a standard way?

@Mikero Users will get assigned to random ID's/locations/$c$.They can have a benefit of knowing the location of another user (or just any specific $c$) in relation to their own ID. No Servers are evolved. So they have access to all runtime variables and can share them as they like. Users will act like adversaries.  I don't know any standard way which is able to do that. No information will be hidden, just their relation.
